# How do I call a function when all tests are finished running?

Tags: testing, rust, rust-cargo

I want to run some cleanup code like stopping database service. I am currently using `std::sync::Once::call_once`:

```
fn init() {
    INIT.call_once(|| {
        //start database
    });
}
```

I put this function in each test. Now I want to run another function which will be executed when all tests are finished. How can I do that?